# How to verify whether an application is launched successfully or not thru shortcut in TestComplete?

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I am trying to launch an application thru its desktop shortcut in TestComplete. I need to verify whether the application launched successfully, if not I would like to know the failure reason.

Testcomplete facilitates calling of some of the Windows APIs using Win32API library. So, for launching an application thru exe I am using Win32API.WinExec() method. Based on the return value of [WinExec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I would know if anything went wrong. But WinExec cannot be used with .lnk files/shortcuts. one alternative is instead of giving the .lnk file as 1st argument of WinExec, I can give cmd /c xyz.lnk which returns true all the time even the .lnk file doesn't exist because it validates on cmd.exe has succeeded or not. But is  there a better solution for verifying this scenaio?

By the way, I am using JScript in Testcomplete.

Comment: Do you really need to launch the application using the shortcut? How about using TestedApps instead? That should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the below script based on this How To entry:
http://www.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/8967/

Here is the example:

```
// One possible approach
function Test()
{
  var strShortcut = "D:\\Notepad.lnk";

  // Run the shortcut
  Sys.OleObject("WScript.Shell").Run(strShortcut);

  // Get the executable file name
  var targetFileName = GetShortcutTaget(strShortcut);
  if ("" == targetFileName)
  {
    Runner.Halt("The target file does not exist");
  }

  // Try to find a process with the executable name used in the shortcut
  var foundProc = Sys.FindChild("Path", targetFileName)

  // Process the result
  if (foundProc.Exists)
    Log.Message("The applicated started successfully: " + targetFileName);
  else
    Log.Warning("The applicated did not start: " + targetFileName);
}

function GetShortcutTaget(shortcutFileName)
{
  var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

  if (fso.FileExists(shortcutFileName)) {
    var shortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(shortcutFileName);
    return shortcut.TargetPath;
  }

  return "";
}
```